# Connection error to Exchange Server SOMETIMES fails. Why?

Tags: c#-4.0, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am succesfully connecting and receiving mails in Exchange mailbox but sometimes (I mean 5 times in a day) connection fails and this Exception thrown: **Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.** I do not have any idea why sometimes it connects successfully and do its job without having any problem and sometimes fails. Here is the part of code:

```
ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
_service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");
_service.AutodiscoverUrl("mailbox@address.com");
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(1000));
Console.WriteLine("There are " + (findResults.Items.Count) + " emails in Inbox");
```

Is there any problem with this code? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After years of dealing with EWS in many different environments, all I can say is that the Client Access Servers are subject to all kinds of burps and hiccups.  They have a tendency to crash and restart, so perhaps you are catching them at a "bad time," and need to retry.  It's unfortunate, but EWS seems to be a endless source of errors that you think "should not happen."